# Patch .net executable via hex editor

Tags: .net, decompiler

**What I am trying to do:**

I have an .exe written in C#. Ilspy shows the code. Inside it has a class `DoWork` with static field `SomeValue`:

```
// Program.DoWork
public static int SomeValue => 15;
```

In code, however, it's not a field but a getter function:

```
// return 15;
IL_0000: ldc.i4.s 15
IL_0002: ret
```

and I want to modify this function to return 127 instead. I've found the location of the function inside .exe binary dump:

```
0x123456  1f 0f 2a
```

I've modified .exe in HxD editor so new binary dump has this:

```
0x123456  1f 7f 2a
```

When I open modified .exe with Ilspy it shows:

```
// Program.DoWork
public static int SomeValue => 127;
```

So all seems well, but it doesn't work. The modified .exe still runs as if `SomeValue` is `15`.

**Questions:**

1. Is this a valid approach to modifying .net assembly?
2. If yes, what am I missing?

Comment: yes, this should work, for the missing part hard to say, w/o looking into the binary

Comment: @PawełŁukasik is IL translated every time exe is run, can it be that x86 representation is cached somewhere?

Comment: unless it's ngen-ed it is compiled every time you run it

Comment: It probably is, how do I check this?

Comment: `ngen display` will list all of the ngen'ed assemblies installed on the system

Comment: turned out it's a "ready to run" executable which has both IL and x86 code inside, supposedly it would JIT compile only on non-x86 machine or something; anyway patching x86 part worked

Comment: ok, that's a recent new thing in .net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out the executable is a [ReadyToRun](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/ready-to-run) executable, so it contains both IL and prebuilt x86-64 image. Modifying IL wasn't working because only x86 image was used at runtime. Modifying x86 image worked for me. ILSpy is capable of showing ReadyToRun image alongside C# and IL.